# Nestjs: Cant implement mutiple GET methods in same controller

Tags: node.js, swagger, nestjs

I have some weird issue here. I have 2 get method which is one get staff list by companyId & get staff details by staffId. Second method `getStaffById` doesn't work. If I comment out the first get method `getStaffByCompanyId`, second working as expected. Looks like first get method blocking second method. Did I missed anything here?

```
@Controller('staff')
@ApiTags('Staff')
export class StaffController {
  constructor(private staffService: StaffService) {}

  @Get(':companyId')
  @ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.OK,
    description: 'Return staffs by id',
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
    description: 'Unauthorized',
    type: Error,
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
    description: 'Get particular staff details',
    type: Error,
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
    description: 'Internal server error',
    type: Error,
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY,
    description: 'Internal communication error',
    type: Error,
  })
  @ApiOperation({
    operationId: 'getStaffByCompanyId',
    summary: 'Get staff list that attach to the company',
  })
  async getStaffByCompanyId(@Param('companyId') companyId: string): Promise<IStaff[]> {
    return await this.staffService.getStaffByCompanyId(companyId);
  }

  @Get(':staffId')
  @ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.OK,
    description: 'Return staff by id',
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
    description: 'Unauthorized',
    type: Error,
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
    description: 'Get particular staff details',
    type: Error,
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
    description: 'Internal server error',
    type: Error,
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY,
    description: 'Internal communication error',
    type: Error,
  })
  @ApiOperation({
    operationId: 'getStaffById',
    summary: 'Get staff profile details',
  })
  async getStaffById(@Param('staffId') staffId: string): Promise<IStaff> {
    return await this.staffService.getStaffById(staffId);
  }
}
```

Comment: to add to Jay response, you have to do some reading on the concept of a "resource" in a REST API. Because staff and company are different objects, they deserve different paths

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Express (what Nest is most likely using under the hood for you) cannot differentiate between

```js
app.get('/:companyId', (req, res, next) => {})
```

and

```js
app.get('/:staffId', (req, res, next) => {})
```

Because all it can see is that there will be a request, with some sort of generic parameter coming in as a string, so while you may know that a `companyId` starts with a `C` and a `staffId` starts with an `S`, there's no way to tell that to Express, and because of this, there's no way to tell Nest to tell Express either. The best thing you can do is add a prefix like `/comapny/:companyId` and `/staff/:staffId` to your routes, to make sure they stay separated.